# Retrieve Data from a SQL Database to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Now, every time run the script, all data is overwritten. How to do so at the next request, select only new data and add it below the existing data in the sheet?  Thanks!
I use this script:

```
var server = 'server';
var port = 3306;
var dbName = 'name';
var username = 'mane';
var password = 'pass';
var url = 'jdbc:mysql://'+server+':'+port+'/'+dbName;

function readData() {
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
var stmt = conn.createStatement();
var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT order_id, firstname FROM id_order ORDER BY id_order.order_id 
ASC');
var metaData=results.getMetaData();
var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet_sql');
sheet.clearContents();
var arr=[];

for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
arr.push(metaData.getColumnName(col + 1));
}

sheet.appendRow(arr);

while (results.next()) {
arr=[];
for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
}
sheet.appendRow(arr);
}

results.close();
stmt.close();
sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, numCols+1);
}

ScriptApp.newTrigger('readData')

.timeBased()

.everyHours(2)

.create();
```

Comment: what's the purpose of `sheet.clearContents()`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code my guess is that you are actually emptying the sheet (`clearContents()`) every time you get the results of the Database.

If you wish to change that behavior and avoid using `clearContents()` you will need to update your SQL statement to exclude all of the already retrieved `order_id`.

If you don't have too much records you can just expand your SQL statement to include [`NOT IN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) clause that would leave out all the records that you have in your sheet.

Alternatively if your variable `order_id` is ordered (increase or decrease in an expected way) you could use the [`BETWEEN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) clause using your *min* `order_id` and *max* `order_id` in your spreadsheet.

If all the previous options are not viable for you, you may take all the records in the SQL statement and then check in *Apps Script* if the record has been already inserted previously, but at this point you are basically doing the same work you were doing before, because you will need to check for every single record retrieved of the database.

---

Although If you are able to you could create a column/table in the SQL database to store all the already inserted records, so you could just retrieve all the non-inserted records in one single statement.

Comment: something like this?  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT order_id, firstname FROM id_order WHERE order_id NOT IN (Sheet_sql!A:A)')

Comment: It will dependent on what your data in column A is, but you need to create a string to encapsulate all your already inserted values. So use [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation), then [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them together to form a parentiss like `NOT IN (id1, id2, id3, id4)`.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try!